# pandas dataframe - searching for numbers

Tags: python, pandas

On the column named "criacao" I have some data stored as object, and they are, for example, "2022-01-03 10:20:40" as df.head(1) and "2022-12-01 10:33:25" as df.tail(1).

I want to extract the data for every 3 months and store in a variable.

I am doing the following and it works for the first month:

```
fd_pri_tri = (df_fresh
               [(df_fresh['criacao']
               .str.contains('2022-01'))
               ]
             )
```

As soon as I try adding the code for month two and three, the var goes blank.

```
fd_pri_tri = (df_fresh
                   [(df_fresh['criacao']
                     .str.contains('2022-01'))
                    &(df_fresh['criacao']
                      .str.contains('2022-02'))
                    &(df_fresh['criacao']
                      .str.contains('2022-03'))
                   ]
             )
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: use **|** instead of **&**

Comment: You need logical or, not logical and.
With logical ands, if one of the conditions is False the whole result is False.

Comment: @Clegane it works, indeed, but doesn't make sense to me. Why would I get this OR that if I want to get this AND that?

Answer (score 0):

An option is to convert the `criacao` date string value to a python datetime data type, review the month for this date, and then assign that month to a specific quarter.

- Month 1-3, assigned to Quarter 1
- Month 4-6, assigned to Quarter 2
- Month 7-9, assigned to Quarter 3
- Month 10-12, assigned to Quarter 4

Pandas lets you use a function to apply the logic on each value of a column and output to a new column using `apply` and `lambda`

```
# import datetime
from datetime import datetime

def assign_quarter(criacao):
    # convert format from string to datetime 
    criacao_formatted = datetime.strptime(criacao, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    # return quarter of year
    return (criacao_formatted.month-1)//3

# make a new column for the criacao quarter
df_fresh['criacao_quarter'] = df_fresh.apply(lambda x: assign_quarter(x['criacao']))
```

More about `apply` here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Then there are a couple options for how to extract the `criacao` values and create the `fd_pri_tri` variable,

like this

`fd_pri_tri = (df_fresh.query('criacao_quarter == 1')['criacao'])`

or this

`fd_pri_tri = (df_fresh.loc[df_fresh['criacao_quarter'] == 1, 'criacao'])`